# how to display equations correctly(alignement)? what could be the reason of the non appearance of some references while others work fine?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

[image: the long dash problem]

[image: thank you for help abouammar( for the equation alignement),here is the code of the references'problem]

------ soory I can not publish more than 2 photos that way I mixed them..

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. For example, it's a common practice to embed your [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in the question. Moreover, please do not use full caps when typing, it is perceived as if your where shouting the question!

Comment: Note that your link to the code is password protected! So we can't access. That's exactly a reason why it's better to put it directly into the question.  A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Lastly, your question is not clear at all. Please rephrase it. If you have several issues,  it is better to ask several questions.

Comment: does this question have anything to do with bibliographies? why have you tagged it with bibtex and bibliographies tags?

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but this question is bad in several respects. The link asks to sign up to Overleaf, which personally will never do; the code producing the wrong display is missing; you most probably get several error messages trying to produce it.

Comment: I am soory for  not being clear ( maybe one reason that I am not a native english speaker, : but I have tried). soory for the link because I did not find how to put the whole project  since if I put some of it maybee it works fine ( and you could not help me) so I would like to put the wole of it to see the problm with me it s the first time that I use overleaf and I have not know that you can not acced to it soory( am going to post some photo so that you could see it clearly ..) I would like to put the code but It will be a bit long...

Comment: the problem is that :  each time two or more continuous items in the reference list have the exact same authors, then the authors of the second and subsequent items are replaced with a long dash(I have added a screeshot it is the fifth reference I have tried acm bib.style but has not work correctly. as you can see there are some references do not appear (replaced by  [?]) while other work well I does know why ! and how to correct it please if there is an email adress so that I can sent the whole project I will be grateful.

Comment: The bibliography style employed by you determines things like the replacement of repeated authors' names with long dashes. If you want to prohibit such replacements, you must switch to a different bibliography style.

Comment: hello Mico I have tried siam and acm but it does not work, moreover some of the references does not appear they are replaced by [?] and the other are okey .. do not know what to do ( and thank you for your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not so clear, but here is the system of equations aligned at the first `=` sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left\{ \begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial W_N}&=0 \rightarrow W_N=\sum_{k=1}^{L'}\alpha_k^{''}y_k^{}\varphi_2^{}(x_k^{}N)\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial W_b}&=0 \rightarrow W_N=\sum_{k=1}^{L'}\alpha_k^{''}y_k^{}=0\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial W_{e_k}}&=0 \rightarrow \gamma e_k^{}k=1,2,\dots,L'\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial W_{\alpha_k^{''}}}&=0 \rightarrow k\biggl[\binom{W_M}{W_N}^T\binom{\varphi_1^{}{x_{KM}^{}}}{\varphi_2^{}{x_{KN}^{}}}+b\biggr]-1+e_k^{}=0\\
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]